# How to get data from php with http.post and then save it in SharedPreferences?

Tags: php, flutter, dart, sharedpreferences

I tried to get data and then save it in `SharedPreference`. I dont know what's wrong, because i make a conditional if the first query `isset`, then it will execute the second query. Like this:

```
    include "conn.php";

    $response    =   array();
    $name        =   $_POST['name'];
    $age         =   $_POST['age'];
    $bookingID   =   $_POST['id'];

    $query = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT orderID FROM tb_order WHERE bookingID = '$bookingID' ");

    if (isset($query)) {
        # code...
        $order = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
        $queryResult = $connect->query("INSERT INTO tb_nameage (name, age, orderID) VALUES ('$name', '$age', '".$order['orderID']."') ");
        $response['id'] = $order['orderID'];
        echo json_encode($response);
    } else {
        # code...
        $response['message']="Failed";
        echo json_encode($response);     
    }
```

And in dart file i have a code to get the data and save it in `SharedPreference` like this:

```
delayedSend() async{
    await inputData().then((_){
      getID();
    });
  }

inputData() async{
    var url = "http://ip/apts/addNameAge.php";
    var respon;
    respon = await http.post(url, body: {
      "name": name, 
      "age": age,
      "id" : bookingID
    });
    
    var datauser = json.decode(respon.body);
    setState(() {
      orderID = datauser['id'];
    });
  }

getID() async{
    SharedPreferences preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    setState(() {
      preferences.setString('orderID', orderID);
    });
  }
```

i call the `delayedSend` method in a button that navigate to second page. In second page,  i want to display that `orderID` using `getString` from SharedPreference but what i get is `null` value. When i check database, the data is inserted, it's mean the query is `isset` right? So, do you know what's wrong with my code? Thanks

Comment: First print the order id and check weather it is returning or not after the http request

Comment: i add print after http request, but in log it's not showing anything

Comment: did you try print(datauser); ?

Comment: no, i try print(orderID)

Comment: try print(datauser); after http and if it returns null, there is a problem in your php code

Comment: same, it didnt showing anything in log

Comment: so there should be a problem in your php code

Comment: do you know what is that? like i said before, the data is successfully inserted in database, it's mean the query is `isset` and execute `$queryResult` right?

Comment: try without using isset if($query)

Comment: by the way, i tried using postman and it's returning the data(orderID)